# Multithreaded server take input from one client and signal the other

Tags: java, server, client

I'm working on a problem from Java How-to-Code, question 28.20.  The book set up a multithreaded client/server to allow two users to play tic tac toe against each other.  The problem asks us to modify the existing code to add certain features.  The one that I am stuck on is to add a "New Game" button.  I have added the button, and gotten the client that presses the button to notify the server, but what I can't figure out how to do, is have the server send a message to the other client.  Right now, it will only respond back to the one that pressed the button.  How can I get it to send a message to either the other or to both clients?  Thanks.

Here is the client code:

```
// Fig. 27.15: TicTacToeClient.java
// Client side of client/server Tic-Tac-Toe program.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;

public class TicTacToeClient extends JFrame implements Runnable
{
private JTextField idField; // textfield to display player's mark
private JTextArea displayArea; // JTextArea to display output
private JPanel boardPanel; // panel for tic-tac-toe board
private JPanel panel2; // panel to hold board
private JButton playAgain;
private JButton disconnect;
private Square[][] board; // tic-tac-toe board
private Square currentSquare; // current square
private Socket connection; // connection to server
private Scanner input; // input from server
private Formatter output; // output to server
private String ticTacToeHost; // host name for server
private String myMark; // this client's mark
private boolean myTurn; // determines which client's turn it is
private final String X_MARK = "X"; // mark for first client
private final String O_MARK = "O"; // mark for second client

// set up user-interface and board
public TicTacToeClient( String host )
{
    ticTacToeHost = host; // set name of server
    displayArea = new JTextArea( 4, 30 ); // set up JTextArea
    displayArea.setEditable( false );
    add( new JScrollPane( displayArea ), BorderLayout.SOUTH );

    boardPanel = new JPanel(); // set up panel for squares in board
    boardPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 3, 0, 0 ) );

    board = new Square[ 3 ][ 3 ]; // create board

    // loop over the rows in the board
    for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
    {
        // loop over the columns in the board
        for ( int column = 0; column < board[ row ].length; column++ )
        {
            // create square
            board[ row ][ column ] = new Square( " ", row * 3 + column );
            boardPanel.add( board[ row ][ column ] ); // add square
        } // end inner for
    } // end outer for


    idField = new JTextField(); // set up textfield
    idField.setEditable( false );
    add(idField, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    panel2 = new JPanel(); // set up panel to contain boardPanel
    panel2.add(boardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // add board panel
    add( panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // add container panel

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0,5));
    playAgain = new JButton("Play again?");
    playAgain.setFont(new Font("NewFont",Font.PLAIN,12));
    playAgain.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPanel.add(playAgain, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    disconnect = new JButton("Disconnect");
    disconnect.setFont(new Font("NewFont2", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    buttonPanel.add(disconnect, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    setSize( 350, 250 ); // set size of window
    setVisible( true ); // show window

    startClient();
} // end TicTacToeClient constructor

// start the client thread
public void startClient()
{
    try // connect to server and get streams
    {
        // make connection to server
        connection = new Socket(
                InetAddress.getByName( ticTacToeHost ), 12345 );

        // get streams for input and output
        input = new Scanner( connection.getInputStream() );
        output = new Formatter( connection.getOutputStream() );
    } // end try
    catch ( IOException ioException )
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    } // end catch

    // create and start worker thread for this client
    ExecutorService worker = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1 );
    worker.execute( this ); // execute client
} // end method startClient

// control thread that allows continuous update of displayArea
public void run()
{
    myMark = input.nextLine(); // get player's mark (X or O)

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    // display player's mark
                    idField.setText( "You are player \"" + myMark + "\"" );
                } // end method run
            } // end anonymous inner class
    ); // end call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater

    myTurn = ( myMark.equals( X_MARK ) ); // determine if client's turn

    playAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output.format("New Game\n");
            output.flush();

            // loop over the rows in the board
            for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
            {
                // loop over the columns in the board
                for ( int column = 0; column < board[ row ].length;column++ )
                {
                    // create square
                    setMark(board[row][column], "");
                } // end inner for
            } // end outer for
        }
    });

    // receive messages sent to client and output them
    while ( true )
    {
        if ( input.hasNextLine() )
            processMessage( input.nextLine() );
    } // end while


} // end method run

// process messages received by client
private void processMessage( String message )
{
    // valid move occurred
    if ( message.equals( "Valid move." ) )
    {
        displayMessage( "Valid move, please wait.\n" );
        setMark( currentSquare, myMark ); // set mark in square
    } // end if
    else if ( message.equals( "Invalid move, try again" ) )
    {
        displayMessage( message + "\n" ); // display invalid move
        myTurn = true; // still this client's turn
    } // end else if
    else if ( message.equals( "Opponent moved" ) )
    {
        int location = input.nextInt(); // get move location
        input.nextLine(); // skip newline after int location
        int row = location / 3; // calculate row
        int column = location % 3; // calculate column

        setMark(  board[ row ][ column ],
                ( myMark.equals( X_MARK ) ? O_MARK : X_MARK ) ); // mark move
        displayMessage( "Opponent moved. Your turn.\n" );
        myTurn = true; // now this client's turn
    } // end else if
    else if(message.equals("Game over. Players Tied")){
        int location = input.nextInt(); // get move location
        input.nextLine(); // skip newline after int location
        int row = location / 3; // calculate row
        int column = location % 3; // calculate column
        setMark(  board[ row ][ column ],
                ( myMark.equals( X_MARK ) ? O_MARK : X_MARK ) ); // mark move
        displayMessage("Game over. Players tied");
        playAgain.setEnabled(true);
    }//else if
    else if(message.equals("Game over, you lose")){
        int location = input.nextInt(); // get move location
        input.nextLine(); // skip newline after int location
        int row = location / 3; // calculate row
        int column = location % 3; // calculate column
        setMark(  board[ row ][ column ],
                ( myMark.equals( X_MARK ) ? O_MARK : X_MARK ) ); // mark move
        displayMessage("Game over, you lose.");
        playAgain.setEnabled(true);
    }//else if
    else if(message.equals("Game over. You win!")){
        displayMessage("Game over. You win!");
        playAgain.setEnabled(true);
    }else if(message.equals("New Game")){
        displayMessage("\nNew game requested");
        // loop over the rows in the board
        for ( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++ )
        {
            // loop over the columns in the board
            for ( int column = 0; column < board[ row ].length; column++ )
            {
                // create square
                setMark(board[row][column], "");
            } // end inner for
        } // end outer for
        playAgain.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else
        displayMessage( message + "\n" ); // display the message
} // end method processMessage

// manipulate displayArea in event-dispatch thread
private void displayMessage( final String messageToDisplay )
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    displayArea.append( messageToDisplay ); // updates output
                } // end method run
            }  // end inner class
    ); // end call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater
} // end method displayMessage

// utility method to set mark on board in event-dispatch thread
private void setMark( final Square squareToMark, final String mark )
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    squareToMark.setMark( mark ); // set mark in square
                } // end method run
            } // end anonymous inner class
    ); // end call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater
} // end method setMark

// send message to server indicating clicked square
public void sendClickedSquare( int location )
{
    // if it is my turn
    if ( myTurn )
    {
        output.format( "%d\n", location ); // send location to server
        output.flush();
        myTurn = false; // not my turn any more
    } // end if
} // end method sendClickedSquare

// set current Square
public void setCurrentSquare( Square square )
{
    currentSquare = square; // set current square to argument
} // end method setCurrentSquare

// private inner class for the squares on the board
private class Square extends JPanel
{
    private String mark; // mark to be drawn in this square
    private int location; // location of square

    public Square( String squareMark, int squareLocation )
    {
        mark = squareMark; // set mark for this square
        location = squareLocation; // set location of this square

        addMouseListener(
                new MouseAdapter()
                {
                    public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e )
                    {
                        setCurrentSquare( Square.this ); // set current

                        // send location of this square
                        sendClickedSquare( getSquareLocation() );
                    } // end method mouseReleased
                } // end anonymous inner class
        ); // end call to addMouseListener
    } // end Square constructor

    // return preferred size of Square
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension( 30, 30 ); // return preferred size
    } // end method getPreferredSize

    // return minimum size of Square
    public Dimension getMinimumSize()
    {
        return getPreferredSize(); // return preferred size
    } // end method getMinimumSize

    // set mark for Square
    public void setMark( String newMark )
    {
        mark = newMark; // set mark of square
        repaint(); // repaint square
    } // end method setMark

    // return Square location
    public int getSquareLocation()
    {
        return location; // return location of square
    } // end method getSquareLocation

    // draw Square
    public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );

        g.drawRect( 0, 0, 29, 29 ); // draw square
        g.drawString( mark, 11, 20 ); // draw mark
    } // end method paintComponent
} // end inner-class Square
} // end class TicTacToeClient
```

the server code

```
// Fig. 27.13: TicTacToeServer.java
// Server side of client/server Tic-Tac-Toe program.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TicTacToeServer extends JFrame
{
private String[] board = new String[ 9 ]; // tic-tac-toe board
private JTextArea outputArea; // for outputting moves
private Player[] players; // array of Players
private ServerSocket server; // server socket to connect with clients
private int currentPlayer; // keeps track of player with current move
private final static int PLAYER_X = 0; // constant for first player
private final static int PLAYER_O = 1; // constant for second player
private final static String[] MARKS = { "X", "O" }; // array of marks
private ExecutorService runGame; // will run players
private Lock gameLock; // to lock game for synchronization
private Condition otherPlayerConnected; // to wait for other player
private Condition otherPlayerTurn; // to wait for other player's turn

// set up tic-tac-toe server and GUI that displays messages
public TicTacToeServer()
{
    super( "Tic-Tac-Toe Server" ); // set title of window

    // create ExecutorService with a thread for each player
    runGame = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );
    gameLock = new ReentrantLock(); // create lock for game

    // condition variable for both players being connected
    otherPlayerConnected = gameLock.newCondition();

    // condition variable for the other player's turn
    otherPlayerTurn = gameLock.newCondition();

    for ( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ )
        board[ i ] = ""; // create tic-tac-toe board
    players = new Player[ 2 ]; // create array of players
    currentPlayer = PLAYER_X; // set current player to first player

    try
    {
        server = new ServerSocket( 12345, 2 ); // set up ServerSocket
    } // end try
    catch ( IOException ioException )
    {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
        System.exit( 1 );
    } // end catch

    outputArea = new JTextArea(); // create JTextArea for output
    add( outputArea, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    outputArea.setText( "Server awaiting connections\n" );

    setSize( 300, 300 ); // set size of window
    setVisible( true ); // show window
} // end TicTacToeServer constructor

// wait for two connections so game can be played
public void execute()
{
    // wait for each client to connect
    for ( int i = 0; i < players.length; i++ )
    {
        try // wait for connection, create Player, start runnable
        {
            players[ i ] = new Player( server.accept(), i );
            runGame.execute( players[ i ] ); // execute player runnable
        } // end try
        catch ( IOException ioException )
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        } // end catch
    } // end for

    gameLock.lock(); // lock game to signal player X's thread

    try
    {
        players[ PLAYER_X ].setSuspended( false ); // resume player X
        otherPlayerConnected.signal(); // wake up player X's thread
    } // end try
    finally
    {
        gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after signalling player X
    } // end finally
} // end method execute

// display message in outputArea
private void displayMessage( final String messageToDisplay )
{
    // display message from event-dispatch thread of execution
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() // updates outputArea
                {
                    outputArea.append( messageToDisplay ); // add message
                } // end  method run
            } // end inner class
    ); // end call to SwingUtilities.invokeLater
} // end method displayMessage

// determine if move is valid
public boolean validateAndMove( int location, int player )
{
    // while not current player, must wait for turn
    while ( player != currentPlayer )
    {
        gameLock.lock(); // lock game to wait for other player to go

        try
        {
            otherPlayerTurn.await(); // wait for player's turn
        } // end try
        catch ( InterruptedException exception )
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } // end catch
        finally
        {
            gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after waiting
        } // end finally
    } // end while

    // if location not occupied, make move
    if ( !isOccupied( location ) )
    {
        board[ location ] = MARKS[ currentPlayer ]; // set move on board
        currentPlayer = 1- currentPlayer; // change player

        // let new current player know that move occurred
        players[ currentPlayer ].otherPlayerMoved( location );

        gameLock.lock(); // lock game to signal other player to go

        try
        {
            if(!isWin() && !isTie())
                otherPlayerTurn.signal(); // signal other player to continue
        } // end try
        finally
        {
            if(!isWin() && !isTie())
                gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after signaling
        } // end finally

        return true; // notify player that move was valid
    } // end if
    else // move was not valid
        return false; // notify player that move was invalid
} // end method validateAndMove

// determine whether location is occupied
public boolean isOccupied( int location )
{
    if ( board[ location ].equals( MARKS[ PLAYER_X ] ) ||
            board [ location ].equals( MARKS[ PLAYER_O ] ) )
        return true; // location is occupied
    else
        return false; // location is not occupied
} // end method isOccupied

// place code in this method to determine whether game over
public boolean isWin()
{
    boolean isGameOver = false;

    if(!board[0].equals("") && board[0].equals(board[1]) 
    && board[1].equals(board[2]))
        isGameOver = true;
    if(!board[3].equals("") && board[3].equals(board[4]) 
    && board[4].equals(board[5]))
        isGameOver = true;
    if(!board[6].equals("") && board[6].equals(board[7]) 
    && board[7].equals(board[8]))
        isGameOver = true;

    if(!board[0].equals("") && board[0].equals(board[3]) 
    && board[3].equals(board[6]))
        isGameOver = true;
    if(!board[1].equals("") && board[1].equals(board[4]) 
    && board[4].equals(board[7]))
        isGameOver = true;
    if(!board[2].equals("") && board[2].equals(board[5]) 
    && board[5].equals(board[8]))
        isGameOver = true;

    if(!board[0].equals("") && board[0].equals(board[4]) 
    && board[4].equals(board[8]))
        isGameOver = true;
    if(!board[2].equals("") && board[2].equals(board[4]) 
    && board[4].equals(board[6]))
        isGameOver = true;
    return isGameOver; // this is left as an exercise
} // end method isWin

public boolean isTie(){
    boolean isTie = false;
    if(!board[0].equals("") && !board[1].equals("") 
    && !board[2].equals("") && !board[3].equals("") && !board[4].equals("")
            && !board[5].equals("") && !board[6].equals("") 
    && !board[7].equals("") && !board[8].equals(""))
        isTie = true;

    return isTie;
}//end method is Tie

// private inner class Player manages each Player as a runnable
private class Player implements Runnable
{
    private Socket connection; // connection to client
    private Scanner input; // input from client
    private Formatter output; // output to client
    private int playerNumber; // tracks which player this is
    private String mark; // mark for this player
    private boolean suspended = true; // whether thread is suspended

    // set up Player thread
    public Player( Socket socket, int number )
    {
        playerNumber = number; // store this player's number
        mark = MARKS[ playerNumber ]; // specify player's mark
        connection = socket; // store socket for client

        try // obtain streams from Socket
        {
            input = new Scanner( connection.getInputStream() );
            output = new Formatter( connection.getOutputStream() );
        } // end try
        catch ( IOException ioException )
        {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        } // end catch
    } // end Player constructor

    // send message that other player moved
    public void otherPlayerMoved( int location )
    {
        if (!isTie() && !isWin()) {
            output.format("Opponent moved\n");
            output.format("%d\n", location); // send location of move
            output.flush(); // flush output
        }else if(isWin()){
            output.format("Game over, you lose\n");
            output.format("%d\n", location);
            output.flush();
        }else if( isTie()){
            output.format("Game over. Players Tied\n");
            output.format("%d\n", location);
            output.flush();
        }
    } // end method otherPlayerMoved

    // control thread's execution
    public void run()
    {
        // send client its mark (X or O), process messages from client
        try
        {
            displayMessage( "Player " + mark + " connected\n" );
            output.format( "%s\n", mark ); // send player's mark
            output.flush(); // flush output

            // if player X, wait for another player to arrive
            if ( playerNumber == PLAYER_X )
            {
                output.format( "%s\n%s", "Player X connected",
                        "Waiting for another player\n" );
                output.flush(); // flush output

                gameLock.lock(); // lock game to  wait for second player

                try
                {
                    while( suspended )
                    {
                        otherPlayerConnected.await(); // wait for player O
                    } // end while
                } // end try
                catch ( InterruptedException exception )
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } // end catch
                finally
                {
                    gameLock.unlock(); // unlock game after second player
                } // end finally

                // send message that other player connected
                output.format( "Other player connected. Your move.\n" );
                output.flush(); // flush output
            } // end if
            else
            {
                output.format( "Player O connected, please wait\n" );
                output.flush(); // flush output
            } // end else

            // while game not over
            while ( true )
            {
                int location = 9; // initialize move location


                if ( input.hasNextInt() )
                    location = input.nextInt(); // get move location
                if ( input.hasNextLine() )
                    processMessage( input.nextLine() );
                // check for valid move
                if ( validateAndMove( location, playerNumber ) )
                {
                    displayMessage( "\nlocation: " + location );
                    output.format( "Valid move.\n" ); // notify client
                    output.flush(); // flush output

                    if (isWin()){
                        output.format("Game over. You win!\n");
                        //output.format("%d\n", location);
                        output.flush();
                    }else if (isTie()){
                        output.format("Game over. Players Tied\n");
                        output.format("%d\n", location);
                        output.flush();
                    }

                } // end if
                else // move was invalid
                {
                    output.format( "Invalid move, try again\n" );
                    output.flush(); // flush output
                } // end else
            } // end while

        } // end try
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                connection.close(); // close connection to client
            } // end try
            catch ( IOException ioException )
            {
                ioException.printStackTrace();
                System.exit( 1 );
            } // end catch
        } // end finally
    } // end method run

    // set whether or not thread is suspended
    public void setSuspended( boolean status )
    {
        suspended = status; // set value of suspended
    } // end method setSuspended

    public void processMessage(String message){
        if ( message.equals( "New Game" ) )
        {
            displayMessage( "\nPlayer requested new game" );
            for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
                board[i] = "";
            }

            output.format("New Game\n");
            output.flush();

        } // end if
    }
} // end class Player
} // end class TicTacToeServer
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clients will need to listen to the server. Ideally, the action messages sent by the clients would be independent of the status messages sent by the server. This decoupling allows more robust scenarios than the "each client takes a turn" one you are doing. Specifically, the server would send status messages to all the clients, and the clients would update their state based on those messages, rather than their own actions.